# Passing data from service to angular components

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, angular4-forms

I am reading data from a firebase database and creating some objects based on the data received and pushing the data into a list. But the control goes back to the component before the objects are created or pushed into the list. I am confused to use any life cycle hooks in this approach.

```
Class Service(){

questions: QuestionsData<any>[]=[];

getQuestions(FormKey: string) {

var dbQuestions = this.af.list('/elements', {
   query: {
  limitToLast: 200,
  orderByChild: 'formid',
  equalTo: FormKey
 }
})

  dbQuestions.subscribe(snapshots=>{
  snapshots.forEach(elementData => {
  this.questions.push(new TextboxQuestion({
    key: elementData.elementname,
    label: elementData.displaytext,
    value: elementData.elementvalue,
    required: false,
    order: elementData.sortorder
  }))
 }
}
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to consume this data in my component.

Comment: Don't subscribe from the service. Use the map() RxJS operator to transform the emitted data into what you want. And **return** the observable. The component is the one that must subscribe.

Comment: I am very new to RxJS can you please post some sample code that i can use. How would i map the data without reading it ? To read it and convert the data into Textbox i need to subscribe. I read RxJs documentation but i am not really sure in this scenario how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JB Nizet mentioned in the comments, you should not `subscribe` to the observable and unwrap it in your template as you are currently doing. Angular provides the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to handle that subscription for you. You simply want to map your data to `TextBoxQuestion`'s. You can do that with the following code.

```
class MyComponent {

  questions$: QuestionsData<any>[]=[];

  getQuestions(FormKey: string) {

    const dbQuestions$ = this.af.list('/elements', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 200,
        orderByChild: 'formid',
        equalTo: FormKey
      }
    });

    this.questions$ = dbQuestions$.map(snapshots => 
      snapshots.map(data => new TextBoxQuestion({
         key: data.elementname,
         // and so on...
      });
  }
}
```

If you want to run that when your component initializes, use the `OnInit` lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getQuestions(/* form key */);
}
```

And then use the `async` pipe in your template like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let question of questions$ | async">
    {{ question.key }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can i use if condition while using the map? because i may create textbox or dropdown or textarea type control based on the data

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I thought everything is working fine but when the data is consumed in the child components i am getting errors like  Runtime Error: Cannot find control with name FirstName etc

Comment: That would be a separate issue -- I'd recommend opening a different question for it with more context and I'll take a look.

Comment: Please open your new question as a separate question with more context, editing this answer with your new code isn't the way edits are meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your **service** should be more or less like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Class Service() {

    getQuestions(FormKey: string): Observable<QuestionsData<any>[]>  {

        return dbQuestions = this.af.list('/elements', {
            query: {
                limitToLast: 200,
                orderByChild: 'formid',
                equalTo: FormKey
            }
        }).map(snapshots=>{
            conts questions: QuestionsData<any>[]=[];

            snapshots.forEach(elementData => {
                questions.push(new TextboxQuestion({
                    key: elementData.elementname,
                    label: elementData.displaytext,
                    value: elementData.elementvalue,
                    required: false,
                    order: elementData.sortorder
                }))
            })

            return questions;
        })
    }
}
```

And in the **component**:

```
serviceInstance.getQuestions(FormKey).subscribe(questions => {
    // your code here
})
```

Comment: how would i populate the data  in the view or html page  if i do it this way?

Comment: after get it from the service in the component, you shoud save the returned list in a component variable, in the html just populated with an *ngFor="let question of questionsInComponent"

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: I wish to avoid the loop so i am marking @vincecampanale answer as answer. But both the answers are perfect. Appreciate your help.